# Find the remaining six vertices of a 3d parallelpiped?

Tags: geometry

Given that $P(-1,1,2) , Q(2,3,5)$ are the opposite vertices of a parallelpiped having its face parallel to the coordinate planes. How can l find the remaining six coordinates ?

Is there a formula or do l have to imagine it and see for myself. As far as l can guess, the remaining vertices are

$A(2,1,2),B(-1,3,2),C(-1,1,5) $ 
$D(-1,3,5), E (2,1,5), F(2,3,2)$

I just guessed it but l don't think l can get any other answer, is there a better method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuition here is that a "parallelepiped whose faces are parallel to the coordinate planes" is just an *axis-aligned cuboid*. The remaining six coordinates may be obtained by choosing between the $x$-coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ for the $x$-coordinate of the to-be-determined point, and similarly for the other coordinates.

We thus get $(2,1,2),(-1,3,2),(-1,1,5),(-1,3,5),(2,1,5),(2,3,2)$ as the remaining points.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification .

Answer (score 2):

Think of $Q$ as $Q=P+(\Delta x,\, \Delta y,\, \Delta z)$.

Then assign the $\Delta$'s as
$P+(\Delta x,0,0),\; P+(0,\Delta y,0), \; P+(0,0,\Delta z)$ will be the vertices on the the three edges starting at $P$. 
$Q-(\Delta x,0,0),\; Q-(0,\Delta y,0), \; Q-(0,0,\Delta z)$ will be the vertices on the the three edges starting at $Q$.